# Python 2.3 distutils overwrites shebang with /usr/bin/python instead of /usr/bin/env python

Tags: python, distutils

I have a package that I install on a shared dev system.  I would like the scripts that the package brings in to be available just for my user (or anyone else who asks for it).  To install the package, I am using the following command from the package directory:

python setup.py install --home=~

This does everything that I would like it to do thus far.  It installs my modules and puts the scripts in the /home/$(whoami)/bin directory.

One thing that it does, however, is replace the shebang that I have in the scripts file.  So, instead of the nice friendly `#!/usr/bin/env python`, it replaces it with `#!/usr/bin/python`

Now, since my package is only being installed for the current user, it cannot see modules within the package for import.

So, since my scripts import functions from the modules within the package, running them from the command line results in an import error.

Running an interactive python interpreter allows me to import the files just fine using the exact same text as the import line from the script I want to run.

Does anyone know of a way that I can address this problem?

P.S.  No, I have no control over the version of Python in this setting.  It's 2.3.4 for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: *I forgot to mention the --executable option. I have no idea if that was present in 2.3 or not, but it works in 2.7 to override the rewriting of hashbangs with whatever the current interpreter is. Try that before anything else.*

In the event the --executable switch doesn't work you should be able to write your own setup.py the way you want. The critical thing about setup.py is that it has to call distutils.core.setup(). If distutils is doing something silly when `setup()` is called, add a correction to your setup.py's routine after that:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import os
setup(name='foo', version='1.0', py_modules=['spam', 'eggs'])
fix_hashbang(script_list):
    sed = "sed -i 's/#! \/usr\/bin\/python/#! \/usr\/bin\/env python/'"
    cmd = ' '.join([sed, ' '.join(script_list)])
    os.system(cmd)
fix_hashbang(list_of_scripts)
```

Where "list of scripts" would be a list of strings containing the paths of the scripts to be updated. This is a bit of a wonky solution. I know the --executable thing works in 2.7, and surely there must be something comparable in 2.3 even if the same switch doesn't exist exactly like that.

Comment: Excellent.  I'll look it up, but do you know how to apply that sort of post-processing to the script files only?

Comment: I updated the answer based on what I think you mean by "the script files only". I resort to using sed on the host system, because its the most straightforward way of doing this in my mind (VS using Python's fileinput module or dumping a list of lines, changing one, and then writing the entire file back, etc.). Actually, since its sed, its only going to change exact matches of the bad hashbang, so its safe to pass over all the installed files.

Comment: the --executable option definitely won't work.  It wasn't available in 2.3...I saw it in the python docs and got excited until I discovered it didn't work.  You know, using sed in this situation is completely overkill, because the shebang line can only appear on the first line of the file.  It also seems that that method would only fix the shebang lines for the scripts already in the package; not the scripts where they are installed.  Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: I think you're not getting what is going on here. setup() does the actual copying _and_ the hashbang rewrite. Once that line is finished executing the installation is complete and the files are in place -- as in copied into your filesystem for good. Anything after that is up to you. So if you feed fix_hashbang() a list of the file paths of the scripts with mangled hashbangs they will be fixed at this point, not in the origin package. Anyway, I don't think sed is overkill considering the alternative.

Comment: Don't be patronizing; it doesn't add anything to the discussion.  Fixing each script in a list programmatically is not elementary.  Since the --home argument is passed as an argument to setup.py, I would first have to parse that out myself.  Then use it to build a path for each one of the scripts.  It wouldn't even make any sense by that time to try to manipulate the scripts myself after setup copies them; I could just move them myself as is and leave the scripts argument out.  No matter what, there is not a clean, elegant way forward, and using command line sed in a python script is neither.

Comment: The whole thing turned out to be moot.  The shebang line wasn't the issue.  I needed to add my home directory's python lib folder added to the PYTHONPATH.  Thanks again for your advice, however.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be patronizing. Obviously we have a different idea of what constitutes triviality (and patronization). That said, familiarity in an area has a lot more to do with how developers rate difficulty. Glad you found your solution.